# Query specific columns of type relationships in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with some text fields and a lot of many to many relationships. I'm having trouble querying *only some* of the fields. Here's how I query the table:

```
with db.session(raise_err=True) as session:
    result = session.query(
        ClientKnowledge
    ).options(
        *[defaultload(getattr(ClientKnowledge, table.table.name))
          .load_only(KqFactory().get_tables([table.table.name])[0].get_pk().name)
          for table in ClientKnowledge.__mapper__.relationships]
    ).filter(
        ClientKnowledge.id == 1
    )
```

This works fine, SQLAlchemy is doing all the joins for me and uses the `lazy=joinedload` param well.

When I specify fields in the query parameters I have to do all the joins myself, but I don't want that; also tried to use `with_entities()` and to make the query from the other side of the relationship, but got the same result.

Is there a way I can query only specific fields without losing SQLAlchemy's ability to make the joins for me?

PS: I can't really give a complete working example since all my tables are dynamically generated. Please tell me if more context is needed.

EDIT:

here is an example of how my tables looks like

```
@as_declarative()
class RightTable1:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = Text()


@as_declarative()
class RightTable2:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = Text()


@as_declarative()
class Association1:
    __tablename__ = 'association1'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ClientKnowledge.rel_field1), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(RightTable1.id), primary_key=True)


@as_declarative()
class Association2:
    __tablename__ = 'association2'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(ClientKnowledge.rel_field2), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(RightTable2.id), primary_key=True)


@as_declarative()
class ClientKnowledge:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text_field = Text()
    rel_field1 = relationship(
        kq_table, secondary=Association1.__table__, lazy='joined',
        backref=backref(RightTable1.__table__.name, lazy='joined')
    )
    rel_field2 = relationship(
        kq_table, secondary=Association2.__table__, lazy='joined',
        backref=backref(RightTable2.__table__.name, lazy='joined')
    )
```

what i want is being able to query ClientKnowledge.rel_field1.

I have tried:

```
session.query(ClientKnowledge.rel_field1)
```

But i have to do all the join myself.

Comment: The title and the question itself would seem to differ a bit. Do you want to restrict what `ClientKnowledge.__mapper__.relationships` to load, or what columns of `ClientKnowledge` to load? Please provide a sample of your query parameters, some data, a concrete table to work against, and an example of desired results. It does not matter that *your* tables are dynamic. Write a [mcve], from scratch if need be, that others can work on – that way your odds of getting a good answer increase greatly.

Comment: As an additional note, you don't need to `getattr(ClientKnowledge, table.table.name)`. You could just use the relationship property object's [`class_attribute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.class_attribute) property (which is almost equal to your manual `getattr()`).

Comment: I want to restrict what columns to load to be able to write a function that take a list of columns as params and load it, class_attribute is nice thank you

Comment: You're misusing `as_declarative` and the models don't seem complete (read: would not work, if copy pasted as is).